# Sin to the base 0 in windows calculator

Tags: convention

In Windows-10 calculator, if I typed Sin(30 degrees) I am getting the answer 0.5 which is correct but it is displaying 
`sin₀(30) = 0.5`

My question is why sin has the zero subscript added to it?
[image: Calculator Preview]

Comment: It shows that the angle you've entered is in **degrees**. If you change it to radians it'd show something like $\sin_r x$ where $x$ is in radians.

Comment: Thank You Ak19, I understand the radian and degrees options but what does the gradient means? Any links?

Comment: A subscript  $g$ like $\sin_g x$  is used to show the Grade system and $90^o = 100^g$

Comment: No it shows subscript 9 to sin gradient.( https://i.imgur.com/r3bUUiG.png )
Why?

Comment: It's actually a $g$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradian